# In windows x64 platform, which jdk is recommend to install?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do i have to install jdk win64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242703/do-i-have-to-install-jdk-win64)

JDK for windows or JDK for windows x64, why?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242703/do-i-have-to-install-jdk-win64

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to use tons of memory in your Java application or need to access native code, it doesn't really matter too much which one to use.

To summarize:

Reasons to use x64 JDK:

- Need to use a lot of memory in your apps (> 2GB)
- Need to use native code from x64 DLLs

Reasons to use x32 JDK:

- Need to use native code from x32 DLLs.

The `.class` files and `.jar` files produced will be completely identical, so you don't *need to* develop on the same system than what you deploy to.

Answer (score 1):

If you do alot of 64-bit calculations you may find that the 64-bit version is faster.  If you don't you might find that the 32-bit version is faster.  It can make as much as 10% difference either way.

If you want to use more than 1.2 GB of memory, you may need the 64-bit version.

One reason people tend to use the 32-bit version is the belief that this reduces memory consumption.  The difference is minor and the 64-bit version has an option to use 32-bit addresses `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` which allows you to use 32-bit address and access 32 Gb of memory.

In summary, I would just use the 64-bit version and if the memory consumption worries you, use the extra options.